# c++ nested constructors call issue

Tags: c++

I have 2 test classes:

```
class B {
    public:
    B(int i) {
       qDebug() << "B constructor ";
    } 
};

class A {
    public:
    A(B b) {
        qDebug() << "A constructor ";
    } 
};
```

Now i want to create A object with B, thats what i do:

```
int i = 5;
A test (B(i)); //does not work
```

Code compiles without errors, but second line doesnt execute at all. I've made some tests, and code below works well:

```
int i = 5;
A test (B((int)i)); //works

A test (B(5)); //works
```

So, i guess compiler cant interpret 'i' as int inside B constructor call, but why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
A test(B(i));
```

is the same as the:

```
A test(B i);
```

which is a function declaration, not a call to constructor due to a [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse). 
There is a rule that states (S. Meyers, "Effective Modern C++"):

> anything that can be parsed as a declaration must be interpreted as
>   one

To avoid that use braced initialization (instead of parentheses `()`) as functions can't be declared with `{}` braces:

```
A test{B(i)};
```

That being said there are no "nested constructors calls" in your example.

Comment: Yeah, thank you, that explains a lot.. C++ never ceases to "amaze" me